# Is Rsync safe to use on a drive that is in use?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I am setting up a nightly cron job to run rsync (with --delete) to synchronize network shares with their respective backup volumes.

Will I run into any trouble if there is a lot of activity on the source drive during the time that the rsync process is running?

For example, there may be a long running copy command transferring GBs of data that overlaps the rsync cron job. Could there be concurrency issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no straight-forward way to have rsync check if a file is being written to, nor would there be any obvious way to handle it if it did. Rsync will just read bytes from the file synchronously and just see the data as it was when it did the read. Your best option is to find some way to synchronize your backup script with whatever application is writing the files. [This thread](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2012-January/027271.html) on the rsync mailing list goes in to some more details.

Another alternative would be if you're using LVM you could [take a snapshot](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) of the volume and rsync from that. But this wouldn't really solve the problem of rsync'ing incomplete or half-written files.

Either way, rsync will do it's job, so if you aren't worried about whether or not the backup is consistent for every file that was being written to then you should be fine with just rsync. I.e., rsync won't crash or error-out or anything like that if that's all you're worried about.

EDIT: (sorry for all the edits :P) One more thing I just thought of. You could set up a second rsync cronjob an hour or so later with the `--existing` flag to catch up on any files that were being written to without picking up any new files which are now being written to. This will sync any "in flight" changes since the first rsync without running in to the same problem on the second run.

Comment: Thank you, as long as this does not cause rsync to crash, I can handle a little inconsistency. For the drive in question, almost all writes will be additive, leaving me with perfectly fine backups for most of the files.